# Python: Small library for 3d-surface plots without dependencies to Matplotlib/Numpy

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to deploy my python code as an .exe-file, which should generate quite a lot of 3d surface plots. Because of the deployment, I cannot use any library which relies on either Numpy, Pandas, Matplotlib etc, because this will cause **huge** filesizes of the .exe.

Unfortunately, plotly and bokeh only work well in the browser, i.e. generate interactive plots. To make a jpg/png from there, I'd need to also embed selenium browser into my exe for bokeh which is not really what I'm looking for.

That's why I'm wondering whether you know a "lean" (i.e.: small) library to generate surface plots? Apart from that, most of these heavy customization-possibilities are not needed at all, simply a good style and that's it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you meant to ask this question on [https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Actually Im not looking for a SW, I'm looking for an open-source Python Library. But if that's also covered there, than yes :)

Comment: At least they have the [python tag](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).